# Amazon RDS Parquet files To Local MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, parquet

I am trying to replicate an Amazon RDS database to local my local database. I have saved the backups to an Amazon S3 Bucket and get the files using downloadDirectory. The database is stored as parquet files. I have created a spark session to read and import the data to the local database however I am not getting any information on primary keys, indexes, and such. How can I get the information of the tables with the data from the parquet files? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you create a table in your local database with all the primary keys, indexes, etc? Using this way you don't have to worry about primary keys, indexes, etc. Simply read the data and export it to your local DB.

Comment: This is for a staging server so the tables can change periodically, that is the last resort but I would love to make it as automated as possible without intervening manually.

Comment: Then you can get the schema using the parquet file and using that schema you can automate the table creation part.

Comment: Yes, but while getting the schema I don't get the information about index and primary keys.  I am creating the tables from the parquet files but if the new columns were to be index or primary key I wouldn't be able to infer the new rules from the parquet.